# orderId not found in cashfree_pg plugin for flutter on iOS devices

Tags: flutter

When passing the necessary parameters to the `doPayment()` in the flutter plugin, it works properly for android. But when the same is done for iOS, the webview opens and shows that orderId was not passed. But I have printed the list of parameters passed to the plugin and it contains `orderId`.

Answer (score 1):

[cashfree_pg](https://pub.dev/packages/cashfree_pg/) shows a weird behavior when on iOS. While the map of required parameters being passed is of type `<String, dynamic>`, which works for android, on iOS, the map being passed should be of type `<String, String>`. Most probably you have `orderId` of a numeric type, converting it to a string should fix the issue. Also keep in mind to make orderAmount as a string too. This change is compatible for both Android and iOS.